# prevent call same class on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I have a slider to display my menu, this menu slide from right to left to go to next level and left to right to return, but when I clicked on "return", yes, go back but at the same time return to the actual div, below is my code.

```
<div class="total">
    <div class="slidepanel">
        <center>
            <button id="sleft">&laquo;</button>
            <button id="sright">&raquo;</button>
        </center>
        <div class="box-wrapper">
            <div class="block" id ="block1">
                <ul id="mm-1" class="mm-list visible">
                    <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#parent-1">parent 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#parent2">parent 2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#parent-3">parent 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="block" id ="block2">

                <ul id="women" class="mm-list subCat-Mobile">
                    <li class="backMenu"><a class="mm-next icon" href="#" data-target="#mm-1">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i> Return Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-title"><span>title parent 1</span></li>
                    <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#women-features">sub parent 1</a></li>

                </ul>

                <ul id="men" class="mm-list subCat-Mobile">
                    <li class="backMenu"><a class="mm-next icon backMenu" href="#" data-target="#mm-1">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>Return Home</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-title"><span>title parent 2</span></li>
                    <li><a class="mm-next" href="#" data-target="#men-features">sub parent 2</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul id="hilfiger" class="mm-list subCat-Mobile">
                    <li class="backMenu"><a class="mm-next icon backMenu" href="#" data-target="#mm-1">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>Return Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/tommy-denim-mujer/">title parent 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/tommy-denim-hombre/">Hombre</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="block" id ="block3">
                <!-- women -->
                <ul id="women-features" class="mm-list subCat-Mobile mm-listView">
                    <li class="backMenu"><a class="mm-next icon backMenu" href="#" data-target="#women">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>Return previous parent</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-title"><span>title subcat 1</span></li>

                    <li><a href="/femenino/novedades/">subcat 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/tommy-x-gigi/">subcat 2</a></li>

                </ul>

                <!-- men -->
                <ul id="men-features" class="mm-list subCat-Mobile mm-listView">
                    <li class="backMenu"><a class="mm-next icon backMenu" href="#" data-target="#men">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-left"></i>Return previous parent</a></li>
                    <li class="menu-title"><span>title subcat 2</span></li>
                    <li><a href="/masculino/novedades">subcat 1</a></li>
                </ul>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my script is the next.

```
$(document).on('click', '.mm-next', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data("target");
        var others = $("div.menu-left").find(".mm-list").not(target);
        others.hide();
        $(target).show();

        return false;
    });
$(document).ready(function() {

var cur = 1;
var max = $(".box-wrapper div").length;


$("#sright, li.backMenu a.mm-next.icon").click(function(){
    if (cur == 1 && cur < max)
        return false;
       cur--;

     $(".block").animate({"left": "+=24.9%"}, "slow");

});

$("#sleft, li a.mm-next").click(function(){
  if (cur+1 > max) 
      return false;
    cur++; 

   $(".block").animate({"left": "-=24.9%"}, "slow");
});
});
```

How can I prevent hide/show the container the same container? you can check the issue when you clicked on the option "return"?

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj4qoe2r/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, why not just change the class names of your 'Return Home' options to something like `mm-previous` instead of `mm-next`? Then you can do the following:

```
$("#sright, li.backMenu a.mm-previous.icon").click(function(){      
  $(".block").animate({"left": "+=24.9%"}, "slow")
})

$("#sleft, li a.mm-next").click(function(){   
  $(".block").animate({"left": "-=24.9%"}, "slow")
})
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hj4qoe2r/29/).

The reason why it is going both ways for you, is that your selections trigger in both cases. So you need to setup a naming convention that helps you distinguish elements better.